# How to replace os.Stdout with io.Writer (bytes.Buffer, etc...)

Tags: testing, go, stdout

I just slumped my shoulders as I realized that `os.Stdout` is an `os.File`. I want replace stdout with  an in-memory buffer to avoid writing to a file. Is there any way to create a file that lives just in memory (and I don't want to deal with a ramdisk)?

Additional context: I'm dealing with calls to `fmt.Println`. I don't have the option to use `fmt.Fprintln`, which accepts an `io.Writer` instead of going straight to `os.Stdout`.

Comment: The answer is to use `os.Pipe` as [already explained](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10476304/605022).

Comment: Normally you would do such stuff while *calling* your program, not from within your code.

Comment: Ok, the real story is that I'm creating a wrapper over fmt.Println and I want to test that it works without having to look at the console or write to a file on disk. I have to replace os.Stdout as part of the setup of my test and the reset it afterwards.