# How to test a function's output (stdout/stderr) in unit tests

Tags: testing, go, stdout

I have a simple function I want to test:

```
func (t *Thing) print(min_verbosity int, message string) {
    if t.verbosity >= minv {
        fmt.Print(message)
    }
}
```

But how can I test what the function actually sends to standard output? [Test::Output](http://search.cpan.org/~bdfoy/Test-Output-1.03/lib/Test/Output.pm) does what I want in Perl.  I know I could write all my own boilerplate to do the same in Go (as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10476304/13860)):

```
orig = os.Stdout
r,w,_ = os.Pipe()
thing.print("Some message")
var buf bytes.Buffer
io.Copy(&buf, r)
w.Close()
os.Stdout = orig
if(buf.String() != "Some message") {
    t.Error("Failure!")
}
```

But that's a lot of extra work for every single test.  I'm hoping there's a more standard way, or perhaps an abstraction library to handle this.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

One thing to also remember, there's nothing stopping you from writing functions to avoid the boilerplate.

For example I have a command line app that uses `log` and I wrote this function:

```
func captureOutput(f func()) string {
    var buf bytes.Buffer
    log.SetOutput(&buf)
    f()
    log.SetOutput(os.Stderr)
    return buf.String()
}
```

Then used it like this:

```
output := captureOutput(func() {
    client.RemoveCertificate("www.example.com")
})
assert.Equal(t, "removed certificate www.example.com\n", output)
```

Using this assert library: http://godoc.org/github.com/stretchr/testify/assert.

Comment: This is probably what I will do, as it's a more general solution than that provided by @Ainar-G, which requires that I control all of the code which might output something.

Comment: FYI this is not go-routine safe. A second go-routine could reset log back to `os.Stderr` while the first go-routing is still logging.

Comment: FYI: This will only capture `log` outputs and not `fmt` outputs.

Comment: For testing concurrent actions that have log output, this can end up in a race between writing to the buffer and reading from it. For a solution, see my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68807754/7655137

Answer (score 21):

You can do one of three things. The first is to use [Examples](http://golang.org/pkg/testing/#hdr-Examples).

> The package also runs and verifies example code. Example functions may include a concluding line comment that begins with "Output:" and is compared with the standard output of the function when the tests are run. (The comparison ignores leading and trailing space.) These are examples of an example:

```
func ExampleHello() {
        fmt.Println("hello")
        // Output: hello
}
```

The second (and more appropriate, IMO) is to use fake functions for your IO. In your code you do:

```
var myPrint = fmt.Print

func (t *Thing) print(min_verbosity int, message string) {
    if t.verbosity >= minv {
        myPrint(message) // N.B.
    }
}
```

And in your tests:

```
func init() {
    myPrint = fakePrint // fakePrint records everything it's supposed to print.
}

func Test...
```

The third is to use `fmt.Fprintf` with an `io.Writer` that is `os.Stdout` in production code, but `bytes.Buffer` in tests.

Comment: Examples are good for when you have deterministic output and fmt.Fprint is good for when you can control the print code (which you can't if it's in an external library or something). I think most of the time one of these things will be true. If there's a case where neither is true an option to read what is written to os.Stdout into a string would be nice.

Comment: I actually used a combination of option 2 and 3. First I made a printer interface, which is used throughout my codebase. This makes testing my code easy and gives me full control over what goes to the screen. Second I test my printer, which can print various complicated types of output to stdout and stderr, using option 3. For unit testing my printer I simply give it two `bytes.Buffer` writers instead of `os.Stdout` and `os.StdErr`.

Comment: How do you do number 3?

Comment: @QuolonelQuestions - I believe the answer is, change all your production code prints to use an injected dependency.  For example, instead of `fmt.Println(x)` always use `fmt.Println(MyWriter, x)` where `MyWriter` is a global that defaults to `io.Writer`.  That might be a lot of change to production code.

Answer (score 1):

You could consider adding a return statement to your function to return the string that is actually printed out.

```
func (t *Thing) print(min_verbosity int, message string) string {
    if t.verbosity >= minv {
        fmt.Print(message)
        return message
    }
    return ""
}
```

Now, your test could just check the returned string against an expected string (rather than the print out). Maybe a bit more in-line with Test Driven Development (TDD).

And, in your production code, nothing would need to change, since you don't have to assign the return value of a function if you don't need it.

Answer (score 0):

Adapting the answer from @Caleb to testing and stdout, with some fixes from the OP's code:

```
func captureOutput(f func() error) (string, error) {
    orig := os.Stdout
    r, w, _ := os.Pipe()
    os.Stdout = w
    err := f()
    os.Stdout = orig
    w.Close()
    out, _ := io.ReadAll(r)
    return string(out), err
}

func TestMyFunc(t *testing.T) {
    output, err := captureOutput(func() error {
        err := myFunc("arg1", "arg2")
        return err
    })
    assert.Nil(t, err)
    assert.Equal(t, "foo", output)
}
```

Note the location of `Close()`.  Before I moved this above the `ReadAll()`, the read would hang and cause a test error, for the obvious reason (waiting for more input.)