# How to check a log/output in go test?

Tags: testing, go

I have this function that logs the error in some cases:

```
func readByte(/*...*/){
    // ...
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("ERROR")
        log.Print("Couldn't read first byte")
        return
    }
    // ...
}
```

Now, in the test file, I want to check the output error from this function:

```
    c.Assert(OUTPUT, check.Matches, "teste")
```

How can I access the log? I tried to put a buffer but it didn't work. What is the right way to catch this log without change my readByte function code?

Comment: What didn't work about writing the log to a buffer?

Comment: the buffer is empty. the OUTPUT returns "". I check if the log is writing and it's ok but my buffer is always empty.

Comment: So show how you're writing to the buffer. There's no reason that you shouldn't be able to write to a buffer and check it later.

Comment: What is `log.Print`? Go's stdlib `log` package?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

For example,

`readbyte_test.go`:

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "log"
    "os"
    "testing"
)

func readByte( /*...*/ ) {
    // ...
    err := io.EOF // force an error
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("ERROR")
        log.Print("Couldn't read first byte")
        return
    }
    // ...
}

func TestReadByte(t *testing.T) {
    var buf bytes.Buffer
    log.SetOutput(&buf)
    defer func() {
        log.SetOutput(os.Stderr)
    }()
    readByte()
    t.Log(buf.String())
}
```

Output:

```
$ go test -v readbyte_test.go 
=== RUN   TestReadByte
ERROR
--- PASS: TestReadByte (0.00s)
    readbyte_test.go:30: 2017/05/22 16:41:00 Couldn't read first byte
PASS
ok      command-line-arguments  0.004s
$
```

Comment: I'm just trying to improve my understanding of unit testing best practices. In this example, would it not be best to also assert, after the call to `readByte` that the contents of `buf` is as expected (or at least non-empty)?

Comment: I prefer to use `t.Cleanup` instead of `defer` in testing.

Answer (score 12):

## Answer for Concurrent Tests

If your test is running concurrently (for example, when testing an `http` `Server` or `Client`), you may encounter a race between writing to the buffer and reading from it. Instead of the buffer, we can redirect output to an `os.Pipe` and use a `bufio.Scanner` to block until output has been written by using the `Scan()` method.

Here is an example of creating an `os.Pipe` and setting the stdlib `log` package to use the pipe. Note my use of the [testify/assert package](https://github.com/stretchr/testify) here:

```
func mockLogger(t *testing.T) (*bufio.Scanner, *os.File, *os.File) {
    reader, writer, err := os.Pipe()
    if err != nil {
        assert.Fail(t, "couldn't get os Pipe: %v", err)
    }
    log.SetOutput(writer)

    return bufio.NewScanner(reader), reader, writer
}
```

The `*os.File` objects are returned so they can be properly closed with a deferred function. Here I'm just printing to `stdout` since if there was some strange error on close I personally wouldn't want to fail the test. However, this could easily be another call to `t.Errorf` or similar if you wanted:

```
func resetLogger(reader *os.File, writer *os.File) {
    err := reader.Close()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("error closing reader was ", err)
    }
    if err = writer.Close(); err != nil {
        fmt.Println("error closing writer was ", err)
    }
    log.SetOutput(os.Stderr)
}
```

And then in your test you would have this pattern:

```
scanner, reader, writer := mockLogger(t) // turn this off when debugging or developing as you will miss output!
defer resetLogger(reader, writer)

// other setup as needed, getting some value for thing below

go concurrentAction() 

scanner.Scan() // blocks until a new line is written to the pipe 

got := scanner.Text() // the last line written to the scanner
msg := fmt.Sprintf("your log message with thing %v you care about", thing) 
assert.Contains(t, got, msg)
```

And finally, the concurrentAction() function is calling a `log` function (or method if using a `log.logger`, the package actually behaves the same way with `log.SetOutput()` call above either way) like:

```
// doing something, getting value for thing 
log.Printf("your log message with the thing %v you care about", thing)
```