# Can a process read its own "standard out" stream?

Tags: multithreading, go, output, outputstream

How would a process read its own output stream?  I am writing automated tests which start a few application sub-processes (applications) in the same process as the test.  Therefore, the standard out is a mix of test output and application output.

I want to read the output stream at runtime and fail the test if I see errors from the application.  Is this possible/feasible?  If so, how do I do it?

Note: I know I could start the applications as their own separate processes and then read their output streams.  That's a lot of work from where I am now.

Also note, this is not a dupe of [How to test a function's output (stdout/stderr) in Go unit tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26804642/how-to-test-a-functions-output-stdout-stderr-in-go-unit-tests), although that ticket is similar and helpful.  The other ticket is about capturing output for a single function call. This ticket is about reading the entire stream, continuously.  The correct answer is also a little different - it requires a pipe.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to test a function's output (stdout/stderr) in Go unit tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26804642/how-to-test-a-functions-output-stdout-stderr-in-go-unit-tests)

Comment: I don't think this is a dupe, although it is similar and helpful.  Thank you for pointing me to it!  The other ticket is about capturing output for a single function call.  Here I want to read the entire stream, continuously.

Comment: The solution is the same. Every program is just a `main()` function, after all.

Comment: The solution is similar, but not the same.  The other solution has a definite start/stop whereas this is continuous streaming.  Also, the other solution gets output after the function ends.  I want a separate thread executing at the same time.

Comment: Go doesn't expose threads, so that's not really an option.

Comment: As for the start/stop... if you want it to continue, just don't stop

Comment: I've looked at the other question more closely.  I agree mine is a duplicate.  The other questions mentions a pipe and it's for capturing output from a test at runtime.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190092/discussion-between-thebiggestlebowski-and-flimzy).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, You may use `os.Pipe()` then process it yourself:

```
tmp := os.Stdout
r, w, err := os.Pipe()
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
os.Stdout = w
```

Or divert `os.Stdout` to a another file or `strings.Builder`.
Here is the detailed answer:
 [In Go, how do I capture stdout of a function into a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10473800/in-go-how-do-i-capture-stdout-of-a-function-into-a-string)

Answer (score 0):

A slightly modified version of an answer given in [In Go, how do I capture stdout of a function into a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10473800/in-go-how-do-i-capture-stdout-of-a-function-into-a-string) using a [os.Pipe](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#Pipe) (a form of [IPC](https://users.cs.cf.ac.uk/Dave.Marshall/C/node23.html)):

> Pipe returns a connected pair of Files; reads from r return bytes written to w. It returns the files and an error, if any.

As [os.Stdout](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#pkg-variables) is an [*os.File](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#File), you could replace it with *any* file.

```
 package main

 import (
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "log"
    "os"
 )

 func main() {
    old := os.Stdout
    r, w, _ := os.Pipe() // TODO: handle error.
    os.Stdout = w

    // All stdout will be caputered from here on.

    fmt.Println("this will be caputered")

    // Access output and restore previous stdout.
    outc := make(chan string)

    go func() {
        var buf bytes.Buffer
        io.Copy(&buf, r) // TODO: handle error
        outc <- buf.String()
    }()

    w.Close()
    os.Stdout = old

    out := <-outc
    log.Printf("captured: %s", out)
 }
```